# How does python parse and evaluate these programs?

Tags: python

I am bit confused to see that all symbols are not getting reviewed by interpreter, before we start executing the logic of program.

For example, in this listing:

```
def func_twice(f, x):
     f(f(x))

def square(x):
   return x * x

result = func_twice(square,2)
```

**result** is still not visible in Global frame until it gets evaluated in runtime.

and in this:

```
def f(x, y):
   return g(x)

def g(a):
   return a + y

f(1, 2)
```

**y** was not syntax checked until it got evaluated.

If one says, it is due to interpreted language nature and this is the way it is, How one can write Enterprise app in python, which may have many such kind of errors introduced by programmer and cannot be recovered until testing?

Comment: You need automated unit tests.

Comment: This is normal for dynamic languages. The symbols are "reviewed" to the extent that the line is syntacticly correct, but variables are only added to a namespace on first assignment. In the case of _a + y_, y may be in the global namespace when the function is finally called. If that means *not enterprise app* to you - there are lots of other languages out there.

Comment: _"y was not syntax checked until it got evaluated."_ That's not a syntax check - it's a global variable lookup. The syntax is correct, and is checked at startup.

Answer (score 0):

This is because python has no variable declarations. In this code, we do not know if `y` exists when we declare the function `g`:

```
def f(x, y):
   return g(x)

def g(a):
   return a + y

y = 3
f(1, 2)
```

Only at the time of invocation of `g` is it checked, since until that point it can't be known

Comment: as you said, it can't be known, is it a disadavantage for writing big applications, where there can be lot of such errors?

Answer (score 0):

`func_twice` isn't returning the value of `f(f(x))`; it's returning `None` in the absence of an explicit return statement. You want

```
def func_twice(f, x):
    return f(f(x))
```

Comment: @eric:  as you said it is glabal variable look up, but i should get a hint during running of python that y is orphan, instead of realising after entering in function g

Comment: it was typo for writing return, i htink somebody edited my question.